# SQL statement not null query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone explain why in the below statements one is valid and the other isn't when they appear identical (ignoring the fact one is a CREATE and the other an ALTER).

"ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified", why does CREATE TABLE allow for null columns to be added that don't have a default value specified?

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  ID int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Test ADD
ID int NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Didn't you read the error message?

Comment: Column names need to be unique.  The CREATE runs and creates a column named ID.  Then the ALTER tries to run, but the column name already exists.  Just change the Alter column name to ID2 and it will work

Comment: You can't add a not null column without a default. Otherwise it would be filled with nulls, which you said aren't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that a table contains 2 rows of data.
This statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD ID int NOT NULL;
```

(if it could execute) would create a new column and the 2 existing rows would have an `id = NULL` although you defined the column as `NOT NULL`!!!
Do you see the problem?
But for the `CREATE` statement there is not such a problem because at the time of the creation there is no data.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the query doesn't work because the table already has a column called `id`.  You cannot add another one.

But, you can add a new column, so this will work:

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD ID2 int NOT NULL;
```

Or rather, this works *on an empty table*.  You cannot add a `NOT NULL` column with no `DEFAULT` to a table with any rows.  The existing rows will get the column.  But with what value?  It can't be `NULL` because of the `NOT NULL` constraint.  And there is no alternative `DEFAULT` value.